# How to unite 2 Build server artifacts into, one nuget package?

Tags: c++, .net, mono, continuous-integration, nuget

I have a C++ library and a .NET wrapper. I use Travis CI and AppVeyor to build it.

Each build server has its own build matrix (6 in AppVeyor, and it soon will be 6 more on Travis CI). C++ builds into `.so` and `.dll`, while C# into a DLL that requires that C++ DLL to work.

Build is automated (and personally I do not want to recompile my library manually on many different compilers - I want to write code), yet public CI build servers use containerization - thus creating separate artifacts for each build configuration. CI servers allow to perform command line actions on successful build.

I get a new set of packages with each new commit (in case build passes). So I wonder how having separate build artifacts

```
Travis CI
Clang 3.7 + Mono 4.0 -> packageClangMono4
Clang 3.7 + Mono 3.0 -> packageClangMono3
gcc-4.8 + Mono 3.0 -> packageGccMono3
gcc-4.8 + Mono 4.0 -> packageGccMono4

AppVeyor:
    - packageVS11
    - packageVS12
    - packageVS14
```

Send them into nuget sepretly, so that it would be capable to provide for ones that require mono3 one set of libraries and ones that use different VS versions other (specialized)?